# Chrome/Chromium WebRTC screen sharing without plugin

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, screen-sharing, webrtc

*The context: We're seeking a video-conference solution that does screen sharing with minimal requirements. WebRTC-based solutions are great, they work fine on a least Firefox and Chromium. Unfortunately, screen sharing requires a plugin on Chromium. We tried both [Jitsi](https://jitsi.org/) and [NextCloud's WebRTC feature](https://nextcloud.com/webrtc/).*

AFAIU, due to a technical restriction, there are no WebRTC solutions that don't require a plugin for screen sharing on Chromium. Is this correct?

Since it works on Firefox, I assume it is a design choice in Chromum, not a technical limitation in the protocol. Is there a chance it will work in Chromium in the future?

In other words, is this planned in Chromium's roadmap? Or should we look for another technology?

Comment: @downvoter, anything I could do to improve / migrate this question?

Comment: [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @jww but the question was not really about a software alternative because as I assumed, the limitation is not in the plugin but in the browser, so changing plugin won't help. The question was about Chromium roadmap. I just added the context and left it open to alternative suggestions.

Comment: But you asked for a recommendation on a video conferencing solution: *"We're seeking a video-conference solution that ... [add requirements]"*. I believe that's what makes the question off-topic, and why it may be better to ask on another site like [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/). Perhaps the question can be reworded to move it away from a recommendation.

Comment: @jww I rephrased to make it clearer. Close or reopen as you wish. I'm not searching anymore. Just leaving this for future reference.

Comment: Apps like https://meet.google.com don't require plugin. This is on chrome 69

Answer (score 2):

From Chrome 70+ you should be able to use [getDisplayMedia](https://webrtchacks.com/chrome-screensharing-getdisplaymedia/) to get screen stream

Answer (score 0):

If you are seeking No download screen sharing, you can try Dead Simple Screen Sharing. You can share screen on Firefox without downloading any plugin, but screen sharing on chrome does require plugin download for the presenter.

Here a link: https://www.deadsimplescreensharing.com/

Thank you

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts
of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become
invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: "You can share screen on Firefox without downloading any plugin, but screen sharing on chrome does require plugin download for the presenter." Yes, just like the two other applications I cited in my question. I'm afraid this is a Chromium/Chrome limitation and it will be the same with all WebRTC solutions. Hence my question: is there a change regarding this that is planned in Chromium's roadmap?